# php mail function can not send attached pdf file and message body

Tags: php, function, email

I want to send mail through php mail function. For that I googled it and found the code which send mail attached with pdf file. Result is fine, mail send but mail only send attached pdf file it can not send message body.

Here is Code:

```
<?php  

$name        = "myname";
$to          = "receive@gmail.com";
$email       = "sender@gmail.com";
$from        = "myname";
$subject     = "Here is your attachment";
$mainMessage = "Hi, here's the file.";
$fileatt     =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/xxx/ticket.pdf";

$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = "ticket.pdf";
$headers     = "From: $from";

// File
$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

// This attaches the file
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$mainMessage  . "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
" filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}-\n";

// Send the email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {    
    echo "The email was sent.";    
}
else {    
    echo "There was an error sending the mail.";    
}   


?>
```

I can not identify where i done mistake, please help me and give some suggestion.

Note: Don't Give suggestion to use PHPMailer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
$to = "youremail@gmail.com";
$from = "Myname <sender@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Test Attachment Email";

$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "document.pdf";


//$pdfdoc is PDF generated by FPDF
$pdfdoc     = "/opt/transmail/2018-03-07_32_11564_invoice.pdf";
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$message = "Thanks";
$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
echo "mail send ... OK";
} else {
echo "mail send ... ERROR";
}
```

hope this will work for you.